# Dynamically convert CSV field value into salesforce data type

Tags: apex, fields, dynamic-apex, data-types

I am trying to create fields dynamically based on the CSV data. All CSV headers represent the field name in Salesforce and rows represent the values. As all CSV values are in string format I have to manually perform all checks and convert the CSV string value into appropriate Data Type using below function.

to get the appropriate value I am invoking the function as follows which returns the `Object` and later I can use to create dynamic field `sobj.put('closeDate',getValue('DATETIME','2020-05-31 00:00:00'));`

> getValue('DATETIME','2020-05-31 00:00:00');

```
private Object getValue(String dataType, String value){

    if(dataType == 'STRING' || dataType == 'PHONE' || dataType == 'PICKLIST' || dataType == 'REFERENCE')
       return String.valueOf(value);
       if(dataType == 'DATE')
        return Date.valueOf(value);
        if(dataType =='BOOLEAN')
            return Boolean.valueOf(value);
        if(dataType =='CURRENCY')
            return  Decimal.valueOf(value);
            if(dataType == 'DATETIME')
                return Datetime.valueOf(value); //Datetime.valueOfGmt(value)
}
```

Now I am wondering do we have any other better approach to implement here as I really doubt how fisible is to convert `String` into `Phone` data type using `String.valueOf`. Please do suggest more dynamic and reliable approch.

Comment: What do you mean by 'create' fields dynamically?

Comment: For example, creating an pportunity field dynamically like `sObject.put('Close Date', '20-05-2020)` now here Stage field name and it's value is coming from CSV in a string format. But before creating field I need to determine the type of it

Comment: sObject.put(fieldname, value) accepts generic Object type. You don't have to convert the data type, do you?

Comment: The value is in string as it's coming from CSV file. So you never know whether it is date or string or boolean

Comment: Ah got it. posted an answer. Hopefully it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the data type from the `DescribeFieldResult.getSOAPType()` method.
And then have a utility method to convert the String value to its corresponding field data type and return as a generic `Object` data type.

```java
// get CSV Header and build the columns and their data types map
List<String> columns = new List<String>{'CloseDate','StageName','Description','Amount'};

Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = SObjectType.Opportunity.fields.getMap();
Map<String, SOAPType> columnTypeMap = new Map<String, SOAPType>();
for (String column : columns) {
    columnTypeMap.put(column, fieldMap.get(column.toLowerCase()).getDescribe().getSOAPType());
}

Object getFieldvalueAsObject(String fieldname, String stringValue) {
    if (columnTypeMap.get(fieldname) == SOAPType.String) {
        return stringValue;
    }
    else if (columnTypeMap.get(fieldname) == SOAPType.Date) {
        return Date.valueOf(stringValue);
    }
    else if (columnTypeMap.get(fieldname) == SOAPType.Double) {
        return Double.valueOf(stringValue);
    }
    else {
        // other data type
        return null;
    }
}

Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
// the field value assignment here should be based on the CSV header instead of hardcoded
// just for example purposes
opp.put('CloseDate', getFieldvalueAsObject('CloseDate', '2020-06-30'));
opp.put('StageName', getFieldvalueAsObject('StageName', 'Prospecting'));
opp.put('Description', getFieldvalueAsObject('Description', 'My opportunity description'));
opp.put('Amount', getFieldvalueAsObject('Amount', '1000000'));
opp.put('Name', 'My oppt 2020');
insert(opp);
```